# Как дополнительно подписаться на событие которое участвует в привязке INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: .net, wpf

Мне надо в ViewModel или в файле MainWindows.xaml.cs при изменении некоторого свойства привязки bool Edit выполнять какие-то действия. Как это можно реализовать, то есть как подписаться на событие изменения свойства привязки?

В программе стандартная реализация привязки + есть событие начала и окончания редактирования для текстового блока:

```
IsInEditMode="{Binding Edit, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

В классе который используется в привязке Word.cs оно описано так:

```
public bool Edit
{
    get
    {
        return _edit;
    }
    set
    {
        _edit = value;
        Notify("Edit");
    }
}
```

Метод находится в отдельном классе ModelNotify.cs:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void Notify(string propertyName)
{
    if (null != PropertyChanged)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

INotifyPropertyChanged - это не какой то магический системный интерфейс который может использовать только сам дотнет а другие к нему не могут прикасатся. Если вам нужно уведомление об изменении свойства то просто подпишитесь на изменение

```
var model = new ModelNotify();
model.PropertyChanged += OnModelPropertyChanged;

void OnModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ModelNotify.Edit))
    {
        // свойство Edit изменилось
    }
}
```

Если нужно уведомление в самой вьюмодели, то просто измените сеттер. Или можно оверрайдить PropertyChanged если тот virtual, зависит от вашей реализации INPC.

Comment: Спасибо, у меня получилось использовать только наследников ModelNotify (Word.cs из примера), объект базового класса ни на что не реагирует.